# MQ Managed file transfer

Tags: ibm-mq, websphere-mq-fte

I am completely new to MQ world and need help understanding the install.

I have downladed 9.2.0.1-IBM-MQFA-Redist-LinuxX64.tar.gz redistrible package . Now i can see under bin folder there is set of FTE* commands.

**Requirements**:
Need to transfer files from linux server to queue (File to Queue)

**Questions**:

1. Do i need to run FTEcreateagent in my linux host or MQ server?
2. If i run FTEcreateagent in my linux host, does the agent will be visible automatically in windows server?

Comment: Do you have FTE setup on the server?

Comment: Hi Josh - Yes we did. we followed below document and we are kind of confused where to run FTECREATEagent command.https://developer.ibm.com/recipes/tutorials/working-with-ibm-mq-managed-file-transfer-mqmft/

Answer (score 2):

You have downloaded is the Redistributable version of IBM MQ Managed File Transfer product. It can be simply unpackaged anywhere on a file system. But you need to have a MQ v9 or above queue manager running somewhere as MQ is a prerequisite for MFT.

The redistributable package contains binaries and commands for for setting up agents to run transfers. It does not contain MQExplorer.

You need to start by running fteCreateEnvironment command and then call fteSetupCoordination, fteSetupCommands and then fteCreateAgent. [This](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.wmqfte.doc/agent_zip_configure.htm) is the best place to start learning about configuring MFT using the redistributable package.

Comment: Many thanks Shashi for your kind response. This is helpful. We are running MQ server v8 so we cannot use MQMFT in MQ v8 queue manager?. I have been told by IBM folks it is backward compatible . Can you please clarify. Thanks again!

Comment: Yes you can use MQ V8 queue manager. The only reason for mentioning MQ v9 or above is that v8 has gone out of support.